# android - receive data from activity and update fragment with passed data

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an Activity named **MainActivity** and a fragment named **Fragment**!

**Fragment** is in **MainActivity**

---

- i want to pass data from **MainActivity** to **Fragment** so i used this..

***MainActivity*** onCreate Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

                pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);

                tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabs.setDistributeEvenly(false); 

                tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                    @Override
                    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                        return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
                    }
                });

                tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    /*im using appcompat_v7 and above code for material design sliding Tabs*/

    /*code for pass data to Fragment*/

            Fragment Fragment =new Fragment();

            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", "myname");
            Fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, Fragment).commit();
}
```

- and then i retrieve data and want to change UI like this!

***Fragment*** onCreateView Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null){

            name= bundle.getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name+"", 1000).show();

            /*change UI*/
            TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(name);

        }

        return v;
}
```

but the problem is here! i dont know why tv show nothing in screen while Toast return name and dont know why next time when i get tv text, it show that name with toast!

what happens here? someone help me **plz**

---

**Edit:**

***tab_1 xml code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e3dbdb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@_@"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend you use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this kind of thing.

Comment: thanks for your advice @Vucko but isn't there a more simple way ?

Comment: Probably. Set breakpoints and debug your code :)

Comment: post xml for tab_1?

Comment: @SahithReddy i added xml! can you help me more please?

Comment: @mohsensharifye nothing shows up or does @_@ show up?

Comment: @SahithReddy the early text shows up and it doesn't update next